# LTRIM function in C

Tags: c, trim

I am trying to write a left trim function in C. Could someone please find out what is the mistake I am doing

```
int main()
{
  char string2[]="   wind";
  ltrim(string2);
  int new_len2=strlen(string2);
  printf("After trim String2 is <%s>\nLength is %d\n",string2,new_len2);
  return 0;
}

void ltrim(char *string)
{
 int i=0;
 while(string[i]==' ')
   {
    i++;
    string=string+i;
   }
printf("inside function string is <%s>---length is %d\n",string,strlen(string));
}
```

output:

```
inside function string is <wind>---length is 4
After trim String2 is <   wind>
Length is 7
```

Why the string is not changing in the main function after trimming.

Comment: Hint: check where string2 points after your function runs.

Comment: Return `string` from `ltrim` and print it from `main`. And `string=string+i;` should be `string++;` or `string=string+1;`.

Answer (score 4):

Minimalistic solution without using `<string.h>`

```
void ltrim(char *src)
{
char *dst;

    /* find position of first non-space character */
for (dst=src; *src == ' '; src++) {;}

    /* nothing to do */
if (dst==src) return;

    /* K&R style strcpy() */
while ((*dst++ = *src++)) {;}

return;
}
```

Comment: 1+ for seperately handling the 0-bytes-to-copy case! :-)

Answer (score 2):

An efficient approach would be to count the numbers of leading blanks and then move the string to the left exactly this number of characters in one go:

```
#include <ctype.h> /* for is blank() */
#include <string.h> /* for memmove() */

void ltrim(char * s)
{
  char * s_tmp = s;

  while (isblank(*s_tmp)) /* isblank() detects spaces and tabs. */
  {
    ++s_tmp;
  }

  memmove(s, s_tmp, s_tmp - s); /* Please note the use of memmove() here, as it
                                   allows the use of overlapping memory areas,
                                   which is not allowed for memcpy().
}
```

Comment: @user3121023: Absolutetly! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift the contents of the string rather than move the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ltrim(char *string);

int main()
{
    char string2[]="   wind";
    ltrim(string2);
    int new_len2=strlen(string2);
    printf("After trim String2 is <%s>\nLength is %d\n",string2,new_len2);
    return 0;
}

void ltrim(char *string)
{
    int i=0;
    while(string[0]==' ')
    {
        i = 0;
        while ( string[i]) {//shift the contents
            string[i]=string[i+1];
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("inside function string is <%s>---length is %d\n",string,strlen(string));
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works but could you please explain me what does `while(string[i])` means, is it checking just not a `0`

Comment: `while(string[i])` is equivalent to `while('\0' != string[i])`.

Comment: Correct, but highly inefficient, as efforts increase exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest Answer Available it seems:

```
char * rtrim(char*);
char * ltrim(char*);

char * rtrim(char * h) {
    size_t s = strlen(h);
    char * string;
    int x = s;
    while (h[x] == ' ' && x >= 0)
    {
       string = string + h[x];
       x--;
    }
    printf("Inside rtrim() function string is <%s>---length is %d\n",string,strlen(string) - x);
    return string;
}

// We, as I had before, do not use sizeof() on strings,
// We have to use strlen because, as you may know
// we need to compensate for different sizes of types
// in certain platforms. Not all are static.
char * ltrim(char * h) {
    size_t s = strlen(h);
    char * string;
    int x = 0;
    while (h[x] == ' ' && x < s)
    {
       string = string + h[x];
       x++;
    }
    printf("Inside ltrim() function string is <%s>---length is %d\n",string,strlen(string) - x);
    return string;
}
```

Comment: What language is this answer?!?!?  This is a C question.

Comment: C++, I didn't realize we were talking only of C. @AndrewHenle. I will update it.